# Crontab opens on blank page, cannot save

Tags: linux, cron

I am really not familiar with Linux, and only started using it recently, so be patient with me. 
I am trying to control a camera on regular intervals through a script that is called upon in the crontab. When I start up the computer, I can open the crontab file, edit and save, and everything is executed correctly. So my script is fine. (btw, I use gedit as editor)

However, I can never open crontab a second time, unless I reboot the computer first. 
This is what happens: I type crontab -e in terminal and I get a blank page. (Usually, crontab shows first a whole explanation as comments, after which you type your actual commands.) When I then type my commands and try to save the file (/tmp/crontab.something), I get the following message: could not find the file /tmp/crontqb.something/crontab. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again.
After I then closed the file without saving, terminal says "no modification made", which is fair enough..

When I try: crontab -l, I do get the correct content of crontab in terminal.

I don't know if this is relevant, but when I try sudo crontab -e, I get " no crontab for root. Using an empty one. 888" But he doesn't open anything and I get no new input line in the terminal.

After I reboot the computer, crontab -e works fine again, but only once..

Any help is really appreciated!

Sarah

Comment: What distro (and version) are you using? You can also try to change your editor to nano or vi, by typing 'export EDITOR=nano' in the shell (this will take effect only for the current shell session; ... in case there is a problem with the editor itself).

Comment: Thank you so much for that suggestion! When using nano as editor, it works like a charm!

Comment: You might want to learn how to use VI, because nano is not always installed.